# Solving rational inequalities that become quadratics

Tags: inequality

Let's say I had $\frac{x(x+a)}{x+b} \leq c$. How does one solve an equation like this?

What I did was split the answer up into two cases, one for $x+b>0$ and one for $x+b<0$. However, I had to further split these two cases into another two cases each, since I had something of the form $(x-b)(x+c) \geq 0$ for each original case (slightly different for each case). I'm not exactly sure if my method was correct and I can't find anything about the topic on the internet.

Comment: First splitting $x+b$ in cases is a good idea! You can then multiply by $x+b$ on both sides (which you probably did) and you'll end up with a quadratic inequality. What to do with a quadratic inequality? You solve the quadratic equation. Why does that solve the problem? Draw the sketch of a parabola and think about the interpretation of inequality and roots.

Answer (score 1):

First solve $x(x+a)/(x+b)=c$, which (after multiplying by the denominator) is a quadratic.
Those solutions and $-b$ (where the left side has a singularity), if they are distinct, divide the number line into three intervals, on each of which the difference between the sides is constant in sign, while crossing from one interval to the next should reverse the sign.  So the inequality will be true in either the middle interval or the two outer ones.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve
$$0\le c-\frac{x(x+a)}{x+b}=\frac{x^2+x(c-a)+bc}{x+b}$$